# Preencher tela com dados de uma tabela auxiliar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Criei um cadastro de Ordem de Serviço, a inserção esta funcionando perfeitamente, estou tentando criar a página de alteração, neste tela traz todos os dados, só não consigo listar os item na table.

Segue os códigos.

```
CONTROLLER:
        public JsonResult PreencheOrdemServicoDetalheServico(string _codigo)
        {
            OrdemServicoDetalheServico ObjOrdemServicoDetalheServico = new OrdemServicoDetalheServico();
            ObjOrdemServicoDetalheServico.IdOrdemServico = _codigo;

        List<OrdemServicoDetalheServico> OrdemServicoDetalheServico = objOrdemServicoDetalheServicoNeg.findAllPorOS(_codigo);



        return Json(new { OrdemServicoDetalheServico }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

---

FUNÇÃO: (CRIEI A FUNÇÃO POIS NÃO CONSEGUI TRAZER OS DADOS DOS ITENS AO CARREGAR A PÁGINA)

```
 function PreencheOrdemServicoDetalheServico() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/OrdemServico/PreencheOrdemServicoDetalheServico',
            data: { _codigo: $("#idOS").val() },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {

            var result = data.Result;

            $(result).each(function (i) {

                cadeia = "<tr>"
                cadeia = cadeia + "<td>" + result[i].IdServico + "</td>";
                cadeia = cadeia + "<td>" + result[i].Descricao + "</td>";
                cadeia = cadeia + "<td>" + result[i].QuantidadeServico + "</td>";
                cadeia = cadeia + "<td>" + result[i].ValorUnitarioServico + "</td>";


                var y = 0;
                var x = 0;
                var des = 0;
                y = result[i].QuantidadeServico//$("#quantidade").val();
                x = result[i].ValorUnitarioServico//$("#preco").val();
                subtotal = (x * y); // - des;
                cadeia = cadeia + "<td>" + subtotal + "</td>"
                cadeia = cadeia + "<td><a class ='elimina'><button class='btn btn-danger' type='button'><span class='fa fa-remove'></span></button></a></td>";
                $("#detalhe tbody").append(cadeia);
                somar();
                fn_dar_eliminar();
                limpar();

            });

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Erro na chamada da função Preenche Serviços");
        }
    });
}
```

---

TABELA (TABLE) LISTAR ITENS DOS SERVIÇOS.

```
<table id="detalhe" class="lista table" border="1">
     <thead style="font-size:12px;">
          <tr class="bg-success">
              <th>Código</th>
              <th>Serviço</th>
              <th>Quantidade</th>
              <th>Preço</th>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
<tbody></tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Não percebi se querias listar os itens só com Razor e sem JS ou queres construir a listagem com o JS.

Comment: Então tenho uma tabela OrdemServico e uma tabela de itens Serviços, preciso listar os serviços que foi cadastrado para esta ordem na tela de edição.

Comment: Salta a vista o erro na utilização do método [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/), pois deveria ser `result.each(function (i) {...}` e tens de ir adicionando os elementos à `cadeia` com `cadeia += ...`. Ao utilizares o sinal de `=` estás a substituir o anterior.

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua atenção, mas pelo que percebi é que não é possível chamar duas funções em seguida, pois quando chamo separadamente funciona. Não sei como fazer aguardar a primeira função fechar para chamar a outra.

Comment: <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            PreencheCliente();
            PreencheOrdemServicoDetalheServico();
           PreenchePecas();
        }
    </script>
</head>

Comment: Como assim? Qual o objetivo e o que está a acontecer de errado?

Comment: Como mencionei acima tenho a função PreencheCliente,PreencheOrdemServicoDetalheServico,PreenchePecas, todas tem que abrir no window.onload. Se colocar as três juntas acontece o erro informando que a conexão esta aberta, se faço uma a uma não dá erro. já tentei colocar uma em window.onload e outra no (document).ready mesmo assim acontece o erro. Já não sei mais o que fazer. preciso carregar todas as funções ao abrir a tela. Mais uma vez obrigado por sua atenção ao meu problema.

Comment: Então a tua questão inicial não tem nada a ver com problema que descreves. Partilha o código dessas três funções.